# Optimize a simple MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
idTelephone int(11)
name varchar(255)
nameUrl varchar(255)
address text
city varchar(255)
cityUrl varchar(255)
cellphone int(1)
```

with the following indexes:

```
PRIMARY idTelephone
nameUrl BTREE
cityUrl BTREE
cityUrlNameUrl  BTREE   cityUrl, nameUrl
search  FULLTEXT name, nameUrl, address, city
name    FULLTEXT
```

there's a page in my website in which I have to show all the telephone numbers with a pagination.
So I use the following query (for the page 26994):

```
SELECT * FROM dir_Telephone WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY nameUrl LIMIT 269930, 10
```

But it's really slow... how could you optimize a simple query like that one?

The output for EXPLAIN is:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  dir_Telephone   ALL     NULL            NULL       NULL     NULL   269965   Using filesort
```

Without the WHERE statement the result is:

```
EXPLAIN (SELECT * FROM dir_Telephone ORDER BY nameUrl LIMIT 269930 , 10);

id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  dir_Telephone   ALL        NULL         NULL    NULL        NULL   269965   Using filesort
```

The CREATE STATEMENT is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dir_Telephone` (
  `idTelephone` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nameUrl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` text,
  `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cityUrl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cellphone` int(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `htmlPublic` text,
  `htmlComplete` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTelephone`),
  KEY `nameUrl` (`nameUrl`),
  KEY `cityUrl` (`cityUrl`),
  KEY `cityUrlNameUrl` (`cityUrl`,`nameUrl`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `search` (`name`,`nameUrl`,`address`,`city`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: I just edited the question with that output

Comment: You say you have an index on nameUrl, but it isn't used. And filesort on a considerable amount of data is slow. Can you post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`? What happens if you remove the useless `WHERE` clause?

Comment: OK I just corrected the question

Comment: MySQL should be able to use the index, see [manual, ORDER BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html), the very first example. How selective is your index?

Comment: How busy is the table in terms of updates and deletes?  That is, is it feasible to include a row number column in the table?

Comment: What do yo mean on how selective it is? Just in case there are several records that have the same nameUrl

Comment: It's basically a static table, I don't usually update or delete the records. The row number column would be the idTelephone which is the telephone number.

Comment: If you use a separate row number column with values corresponding to  `ORDER BY nameUrl` that will be updated, i.e. by a trigger on insert, update and delete operations will simplify your query: no limit but a simple `WHERE rownum BETWEEN 269931 AND 269940` and an easy to use index. A very good idea of @GordonLinoff.

Comment: I'll try that and let you know, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is add a rownumber column to the table.  One way is to define a new table, just like the old table, but with an auto-incremented column.  Then load the data into it.  Alternatively, you can do something like the following.

```
alter table dir_Telephone add rownum integer;

update dir_telephone cross join
       (select @rn := 0) var
    set rownum = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    order by nameUrl;

create index dir_Telephone_rownum on dir_Telephone(rownum);
```

Then, when you run your query, don't use an offset in the `limit` clause.  Use a `where` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM dir_Telephone
WHERE 1=1 AND rownum >= 269930
ORDER BY rownum
LIMIT 10;
```